# C++ Image Manipulation Errors

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a program which will convert a .ppm image file with certain functions and output the new .ppm file once finished. I am having two issues:

1. The output file will only return half of modified image after completion.
   I thought this may be because the image width and height were being changed during the image manipulation, but I could not find the issue.  The functions to negateRed, negateGreen, etc... work correctly.

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <string>
   #include <fstream>
   #include "PixMixer.h"

   using namespace std;
   int main()
   {
   PixMixer a;
   string inName, outName;
   cout << "Welcome to Pixel Mixer!" << endl;
   cout << "Enter name of source image file:" << endl;
   cin >> inName;

   cout << "Enter name of target image file:" << endl;
   cin >> outName;


   ifstream inFile (inName.c_str());
   ofstream outFile(outName.c_str());

   int width, height, n;
   string word;

   inFile >> word;
   outFile << word << endl;

   inFile >> width;
   outFile << width << " ";
   inFile >> height;
   outFile << height << endl;
   cout << width << height << endl;

   inFile >> n;
   outFile << n << endl;
   if (n != 255)
   {
       cout << "Unable to open file" << endl;
       return 0;
   }

   // convert image file to array

   unsigned short* pixels = new unsigned short[height*width*3];

   int counter = 3;
   while (!inFile.eof())
   {
       inFile >> pixels[counter];
       counter ++;
   }

   char z;
   cout << "Your file choices are: \n"
           "[1] convert to greyscale [2] flip horizontal"
           "[3] negate reds [4] negate greens [5] negate blues"<<endl;



   cout << "Do you want [1]? (y/n): " <<endl;
   cin >> z;
   if (z == 'y')
   {
       a.greyScale(pixels, width, height);
   }
   cout << width << height << endl;
   cout << "Do you want [2]? (y/n): " <<endl;
   cin >> z;
   if (z == 'y')
   {
       a.flipH(pixels, width, height);
   }
   cout << "Do you want [3]? (y/n): " <<endl;
   cin >> z;
   if (z == 'y')
   {
      a.negRed(pixels, width, height);
   }

   cout << "Do you want [4]? (y/n): " <<endl;
   cin >> z;
   if (z == 'y')
   {
       a.negGreen(pixels, width, height);
   }
   cout << "Do you want [5]? (y/n): " <<endl;
   cin >> z;
   if (z == 'y')
   {
       a.negBlue(pixels, width, height);
   }

   //  outputFile
   for (int i = 0; i < (width*height); i +=3)
   {
       outFile << pixels[i] << " " << pixels[i+1] << " " << pixels[i+2] << endl;
   }
   inFile.close();
   outFile.close();

   cout << "Job is completed!" << endl;


   return 0;
   }
   ```

2.My horizontal flip function is not working and when I try to run it it crashes my program. Here is the code for my Horizontal flip function from .cpp class:

```
void PixMixer::flipH(unsigned short pixels[], int width, int height)
{
    int imagea[height*width];
    for (int i = 0; i<height; i++)
    {
        for ( int j=0; j<width; j++)
        {
            imagea[j*width*i] = pixels[i*width+(width-1-j)];
            imagea[j*width*i+1] = pixels[i*width+(width-1-j)+1];
            imagea[j*width*i+2] = pixels[i*width+(width-1-j)+2];
        }
    }

    for (int l = 0; l <(width*height); l++)
    {
        pixels[l] = imagea[l];
    }
    return;
}
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Re (2): Check your math. `j*width*i` cannot be correct, as it will eventually lead to `(width-1) * width * (height-1`), which is certainly a helluvalot bigger than `width * height`, the declared size of `image`. Somewhere in there you're multiplying incorrectly instead of adding.